# Creating a buffer around a raster in Google Earth Engine

Tags: buffer, google-earth-engine

I want to create a 10km buffer around mangrove patches from the mangrove forest raster. I've tried a number of approaches but can't get anything to work. I tried converting the raster to vector but at the resolution (30m) I need it is too big and the computation times out. I also tried to the focal.max tool but this seems to be dependent on the zoom level I'm using and therefore capture only certain patches

```js
//import Mangroves of the World   
var MangroveImage = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/MANGROVE_FORESTS') 

//select the image from the mangrove dataset 
var mangrove = ee.Image(MangroveImage.first());

//buffer around mangroves 
var mangrove_buffer = mangrove.focal_max({
radius: 10000,
kernelType: 'circle',
units:'meters',
iterations: 1
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the `focal_max()` and `distance()` methods are constrained to a kernel of 256 pixels, so you need to either increase the scale or decrease the buffer length.  You can get an approximation using the `cumulativeCost()` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_cumulative_cost)) method:

```js
//import Mangroves of the World   
var MangroveImage = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/MANGROVE_FORESTS');

//select the image from the mangrove dataset 
var mangrove = ee.Image(MangroveImage.first());
Map.addLayer(mangrove, {}, 'mangrove');

//buffer around mangroves 
var buffer = ee.Image(1)
    .cumulativeCost({
      source: mangrove, 
      maxDistance: 10000,
    }).lt(10000);

var params = {min: 0, max: 10000, palette: ['red']};
Map.addLayer(buffer.mask(buffer), params, 'mangrove_buffer');
```